# Problem with ICriteria

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have two classes:

```
public class NormDoc
{

public virtual string Name {get;set;}
public virtual Category CategoryName {get;set;}
...
}

public class Category
{
publiс virtual string Abbr {get;set;}
public virtual string Name {get;set;}
...

}
```

I have form where user can select field (only NormDoc's properties). For example user choose `CategoryName` and `Name`. I have written criteria for Name property:

```
 ICriteria criteria = dataAccessor.GetNormDocDAO().NHibernateSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(NormDoc));
 var test = criteria.Add(Expression.Like("Name", "userText")).List();
```

How to write criteria for CategoryName property? I want something like that:

```
criteria.Add(Expression.Like("Category.Name", "userText")).List();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using sub criteria like this:

```
var x = dataAccessor.GetNormDocDAO().NHibernateSession.CreateCriteria<NormDoc>()
    .CreateCriteria("CategoryName")
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Name", "userText"))
    .List<NormDoc>();
```